# How do you level-shift a sawtooth signal?

Tags: pwm, buck, level-shifting

I am designing a sawtooth generator for an integrated PWM mode buck converter. I have built a constant current source (a simple PMOS current mirror) which linearly charges a capacitor. There is a switch that discharges the capacitor as the desired height is obtained. The value of capacitance, current and the time for which the switch is OFF, determine the voltage across capacitor. This could generate a signal that ramps up from 0 V to a certain height and in a short time, falls back to zero.

This signal is fed to a comparator whose common mode range is around 1 V. I have to add a DC shift of 1 V to the signal so that comparator is properly biased. I tried adding a resistor in series with the capacitor, so that I get a DC shift even when the switch shorts the capacitor terminals.It does work well but fails as process, temperature and voltage/current variations are considered. Is there any other way I could do this?

**EDIT**

Here's the schematic: I have added a resistor of 650 K and the current is 2 uA which gives a shift of 1.3 V. The signal VP controls the switch M3. M3 is OFF for 249 ns and is ON for 1 ns during which capacitor discharges. The voltage across capacitor changes from 0 V to 0.5 V while that tapped from upper terminal of resistor changes from 1.3 to 1.8 V.

[image]

Comment: It makes life a lot easier when folks put a circuit diagram.

Comment: Put it through an inverting opamp configuration with the non-inverting input connected to the offset you want.

Comment: clamping circuit?? But we need a schematic to help you out.

Comment: I am not sure I understood well, but it seems you want to shift your signal *just* because the common-mode range of your comparator starts from 1V, right? Then, what about choosing a more appropriate comparator? Even LM339 includes ground in its common-mode range.

Comment: I'd totally agree with Jim. In fact, I go further. When a question reaches a level where we need to have a schematic in front of us to even discuss it, you, as the asker **must** have that schematic in your question. If it's not in your question, I vote to close it. So please **edit** your question, and use the built-in *schematic editor* to add a schematic.

Comment: Something like this https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4836

Comment: I have edited the question to include the schematic.

Comment: @dim I have already designed a comparator with many other considerations for the common mode I have specified above. That's why I need to find a way to shift the signal.

Comment: @DirkBruere, thanks. Is it feasible to design a opamp just for adding a DC shift? I did not mention it in the question, but this would consume more chip area.

Comment: @AdityaPatil I infer this is an ASIC design. Maybe you should clarify the question with the constraints.

Comment: Show your results. the sawtooth requires a near zero transition/switch time. Did you mean triangle wave? When I needed a sawtooth for 10MHz linear S&H phase detector, I used a triangle wave and inverted it with special transmission gates from complementary outputs at any offset or range I needed with 1ns transition time

Comment: try this http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/4441713900_1484764562.jpg

Comment: Also in future FIRST define your design rules: Vout: range, offset, frequency , Vcc supply, lithography resolution, stability, tolerances. N.B. > FYI to all users.

Comment: N.B. or n.b. "Nota bene" for scholars this is latin means "**note well**" like e.g. means for example... and FYI is of course not latin

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 In the link you've mentioned, the non-inverting terminal is grounded. Would the OPAMP work? Can you please share any documents related to that schematic? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use long-channel PFETS? That will reach down to GND, if not below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it through a summing amplifier and feed a fixed voltage to the other input of the summing amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can level shift and scale the signal using three resistors (R1, R2, R3) if you are willing to live with some signal attenuation.

One end of all three resistors connect together at the comparator input.  Resistor R1 connects to a voltage greater than 1V (a supply voltage).  Resistor R2 connects to a voltage lower than 1V (GND).  Resistor R3 connects to the input signal.


Vout is the voltage at the connection point of all three resistors.
V1 is the input voltage to R1
V2 is the input voltage to R2
V3 is the input voltage to R3

Vout = (V1/R1 + V2/R2 + V3/R3) / (1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3)

For example lets use...
V1 = +5V
V2 = GND (0V)
V3 = the triangle wave input.
R1 = 4K
R2 = 2K
R3 = 2K

Then...
Vout = (5V/4K + 0V/2K + V3/2K) / (1/4K + 1/2K + 1/2K ) = 0.4 * V3 + 1V

You may be wondering how I came up with 4K 2K and 2K for the resistor values.

1)  I arbitrarily picked a supply voltage (in this case 5V).

2)  I arbitrarily picked the supply current flowing through the divider with the input signal grounded (in this case 1mA).

3)  I knew that I wanted to shift the signal by 1V, so with the input signal grounded, R1 must drop 4V across it.  R2 and R3 must then drop 1V (to make a total of 5V).  Therefore R1 = 4V / 1mA.  R2 and R3 in parallel must equal 1K.  There were many choices, but I just picked them both to be 2K.